# Typescript Union Type Record Or Array Of Record

Tags: typescript, types

I Have a method which takes a single parameter which is a union type of `obj: QueryResultRow | readonly QueryResultRow[]`. Since this can be either type of QueryResultRow or QueryResultRow array I need a way to determin which is which. I can do that via `Array.isArray(obj)` but the typescript compiler does not recognise that after that point it is the single record and throws an error. My method is

```
protected rowMapper(obj: QueryResultRow | readonly QueryResultRow[])
{
    if (Array.isArray(obj))
    {
        return obj.map((row) => new Contact(row.id, row.name, row.email, row.phone_number, row.creation_date));
    }

    return new Contact(obj.id, obj.name, obj.email, obj.phone_number, obj.creation_date);
}
```

The error I get is `TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QueryResultRow | readonly QueryResultRow[]'.   Property 'id' does not exist on type 'readonly QueryResultRow[]'.` because it doesnt know its the single record from the point after the if statement. There is no problem in funcitonality because I can guarantee what it is but I would like the typescript compiler to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

1. `Array.isArray()` does not work for `ReadonlyArray` - see
   [#17002: Array.isArray type narrows to any[] for ReadonlyArray](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002)
2. you should use an `else` clause

Example code for typescript 4.6.2:

```js
type QueryResultRow = {
  id: string
}

function foo(obj: QueryResultRow | Array<QueryResultRow>) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(row => row.id);
  } else {
    // typescript knows that obj is of type QueryResultRow in the else branch
    return obj.id;
  }
}

function fooReadonly(obj: QueryResultRow | ReadonlyArray<QueryResultRow>) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    // note: obj is of type any[]
    return obj.map(row => row.id);
  } else {
    /**
     * ERROR: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QueryResultRow | readonly QueryResultRow[]'.
     *   Property 'id' does not exist on type 'readonly QueryResultRow[]'.
     */
    return obj.id;
  }
}
```

The [linked issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002) mentions some workarounds.
I'd just use a simple type-guard in this case:

```js
/**
 * type guard is needed until this bug is fixed:
 * https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002
 */
function isNotArray<T>(value: T | ArrayLike<T>): value is T {
  return !Array.isArray(value);
}

function fooReadonlyFixed(obj: QueryResultRow | ReadonlyArray<QueryResultRow>) {
  if (isNotArray(obj)) {
    return obj.id;
  } else {
    return obj.map(row => row.id);
  }
}

function fooFixed(obj: QueryResultRow | Array<QueryResultRow>) {
  if (isNotArray(obj)) {
    return obj.id;
  } else {
    return obj.map(row => row.id);
  }
}
```

note, that we have inverted the logic (isNotArray instead of isArray), so that it works correctly for `Array<>` and `ReadonlyArray<>`

[Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiAShAznANsFB7AdygF4oBvAWACgooBLAEwC4p1hE6A7Ac2oF9q1AGZxOAY2B08nKELx4AFHgBGAKxbwkqDNlyEoAHygBBRIgCGIADybkaTDnwEAfAEpy1WnSFQFpiyAAdHTo-pZKaq7ulDS0UIgQwHCIMiqqgQC25mAKiPrEzvGEwQyuANyeUHxQEFjo0DFx8YnJqWolFbECVN3CohJSMnJ4aOYM0lggEeqwCHY6jvpGo+Ock2HWttoOei7Rld6+G8GhZuFpUR6xtAD0N1CceMAQLGn06FB4PqCQUOacIAA2gBdSq0BJJFKfdpZHJ5IgFIoEErlSrVWr1K5NG4AKhxYNoOKgAFEUCgAPIoFgABTykEQoCgAHJGEyoOMMA8njUAB4hYCfGQ-aBMrb2XROQzNMYTECzLTixYEEFMwIEqBE2i0vD0xkshhsjkfR4CiB8tiCqDC5kJGVrOViha7FVq66Em4EiGtaHpRidWjdXpUXH4mhE63cODmRAMd4PCAQBiJqCiSRYK0ACxCUGUcG4caEdB5iaYniJGeAwDA6CYd24dGAGbgykCYjwGRuGToYjy6C+wBuABVwBAAMo9uhgAchTAYG4ARgA7AAGZcAJjLHqoInEkmk7wAck8NlZB84FAA3cxYBAsQdSjYAGToAGsIKe3CwrzfoNn741mkhGQAEJjhCDZL2vBBUR6QRt36PchnkFZZQAMSLRMUPtaYNDmbYJSWKAsPWM5NjwxVdjcLF6B8BQQiPYAIIufY3S9KE0g6NEajqBpPRadiYWyXJ8kKeEUX9Kp+DgncBn3YZ0OLBgcPleYdklIwT0dNTCCogDDjo9AGKYyIWKaNi2l9BgJPRHjqPBfiLMyIT4RIUTikYGCA34IA)